# How to build JS function chain or add to anonymous function body at parse time?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, function, syntax

When working on ASP.NET MVC apps that use a layout page with includes (views and partial views) I typically declare a javascript var at the top of the layout page that I assign an js anonymous function to in the view or one of the partial views that will be invoked immediately once the document is loaded. Something like this and in this order once the page is returned from the server:

```
 <!-- top of layout page : static -->

 <!-- ver jquery for bootstrap -->
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //define app's js namespace
 var myApp = {};

 //placeholder for anon func
 myApp.initLoadFunc = null;

 </script>


 <!-- Child View : dynamically added (or not) depending on current view -->
<script type="text/javascript">

//for this view, I want to run this on document load
myApp.initLoadFunc = function() { //do something... }
</script>
<!-- end child view -->


<!-- bottom of Layout page : static -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

        //run init function if populated...
        if (myApp.initLoadFunc != null) {
            myApp.initLoadFunc();
        }
    });


</script>
```

My question is: What if I want to define and assign multiple functions at parse time or add to the anon function's body from additional child views without declaring extra var placeholders? I don't want to do any wonky eval calls. Is there a way to chain add? I could perhaps define a js array and populate with functions, but I'm thinking there is a cleaner way to accomplish this. Somehow using "this"? Any solutions?

Comment: You don't need function placeholders, they will be created when you set a property. So `myApp.initLoadFunc = null;` can be removed completely. Also use `if (myApp.initLoadFunc) {` instead of comparison with null.

Comment: You are correct @vorrtex. Interesting, your comment just made me think...maybe the answer is reflection and if I do use the placeholder object (so as to not conflict with other child functions or properties of 'myApp') then I should be able enumerate thru all the added funcs and invoke. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I can use reflection to invoke all funcs added to a defined js object. @vorrtex brought up a good point about not needing to create empty properties to assign an anonymous functions to, as these will be create for you in JS, but in this case it helps me separate functions added on the fly from other properties/methods that should not be invoked on document load. This works great and satisfies my requirement:

```
<!-- top of layout page : static -->     

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //define app's js namespace
 var myApp = {};

 //empty func for all added anon funcs, to separate those NOT to be invoked on load
 myApp.initLoadFuncs = {};

 </script>


 <!-- Child View (1) : dynamically add anon func to be run on load -->
<script type="text/javascript">

//for this view, I want to run this on document load
myApp.initLoadFuncs.view1Func = function() { //do something... }
</script>

<!-- end child view -->


 <!-- Child View (2) : add another anon func to be run on load -->
<script type="text/javascript">

//I want to run this also onload if this view is included
myApp.initLoadFuncs.view2Func = function() { //do something else... }
</script>

<!-- end child view -->


<!-- bottom of Layout page : static -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {

        if (myApp.initLoadFuncs) {

            //enumerate func properties, use reflection to determine if function, and invoke
            for (var m in myApp.initLoadFuncs) {

                if (typeof(myApp.initLoadFuncs[m]) == "function") {

                    myApp.initLoadFuncs[m]();
                }
            }
        }


    });


</script>
```